# Creating parallel polylines in specific distance of existing polyline using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polyline-creation

I want to create two polylines on both sides of an existing polyline and parallel to it. I use ArcMap.

Comment: ArcMap, or ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: ArcMap 10.8. Thanks.

Comment: If you have many lines then you can Buffer with flat ends, Polygon to line, split the lines

Answer (score 3):

Enable the Edit mode and select the feature you want to make a parallel for, and use the copy parallel command.

[image]

[image]